# How to add a custom button in vuetify select

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a scenario like I have to list a few hundred categories and I have to show them in a select box. Since the list is huge, skip and limit is implemented in the backend, so that it will limit the categories to 20s. My case is like when the user sees the first 20 categories, in the end, I have to add some button stating like 'Load more' so that when the user clicks on it, they can see the next 20 categories. But I have no idea how to add a button in a vuetify select. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    fruits: [
      'Item 1',
      'Item 2',
      'Item 3',
      'Item 4'
    ],
    selectedFruits: [],
  }),

  computed: {
    likesAllFruit () {
      return this.selectedFruits.length === this.fruits.length
    },
    likesSomeFruit () {
      return this.selectedFruits.length > 0 && !this.likesAllFruit
    },
    icon () {
      if (this.likesAllFruit) return 'mdi-close-box'
      if (this.likesSomeFruit) return 'mdi-minus-box'
      return 'mdi-checkbox-blank-outline'
    },
  },

  methods: {
    toggle () {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        if (this.likesAllFruit) {
          this.selectedFruits = []
        } else {
          this.selectedFruits = this.fruits.slice()
        }
      })
    },
    loadMore () {
      console.log('load more ...')
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.26/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.26/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-select
        v-model="selectedFruits"
        :items="fruits"
        label="Favorite Fruits"
        multiple
      >
        <template v-slot:prepend-item>
          <v-list-item
            ripple
            @click="toggle"
          >
            <v-list-item-action>
              <v-icon :color="selectedFruits.length > 0 ? 'indigo darken-4' : ''">{{ icon }}</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-action>
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title>Select All</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
          <v-divider class="mt-2"></v-divider>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:append-item>
          <v-divider class="mb-2"></v-divider>

          <v-btn color="primary" @click="loadMore">
            Click me for load more items.
          </v-btn>
        </template>
      </v-select>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Vuetify 2.x there is an virtual scroll component, but I still found the v-intersect easiest to use...

markup:

```
        <v-autocomplete 
                v-model="selected"
                :items="beers" 
                item-text="name" 
                item-value="id" 
                label="Search da beers.."
                return-object
                autocomplete="off"
                >
                <template v-slot:append-item>
                  <div v-intersect="onIntersect" class="pa-4 teal--text">
                     Loading more items ...
                  </div>
                </template>
         </v-autocomplete>
```

```
    data() {
        return {
          beers: [],
          selected: null,
          perPage: 30,
          page: 1,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getBeers() {
            console.log('page', this.page)
            const apiUrl = `https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers?page=${this.page}&per_page=${this.perPage}`
            axios.get(apiUrl)
                .then(response => {
                  this.beers = [
                      ...this.beers,
                      ...response.data
                  ]
            })
        },
        onIntersect () {
            console.log('load more...')
            this.page += 1
            this.getDate()
        },
    },
    created() {
        this.getData()
    }
```

[Working Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/BOwzZKhFvY)